# RemoteApp using drivers for scanner

Tags: remote-desktop, remoteapp

One of my clients wants to use a check scanner. They purchased software and have a scanner however they do not want to store any of the data on the workstation the scanner is attached to. I'm wondering if we can utilize RemoteApp to deploy the software? I've built a test of the application being deployed via RemoteApp and it seems to work however I don't have a check scanner to test with. Will I run into driver issues or should this POC work?

Setup a test environment using RemoteApp software works fine however do not have a check scanner to test with.

Comment: That pretty much depends on the scanner. Some emulate keyboards and just hit keys, others work via drivers and might cause trouble. Without more details we can't answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should  work ok, but it will often depend on the scanner software. Useally these scanners simply type as if the keyboard was being pressed. So you have to place your cursor in the field on the form, and then scan, and it “types in” what the scanner saw. So, you can launch word, or Access or even note pad for this to work. If  you are using remote desktop, then this should also work. If the scanner does not type keys as it scans, then you can’t use remote desktop, but in most cases it should.

And in most cases, the field (text box) you scan into likely will need to parse out the bits and parts of the string into separate text boxes.

So given how most scanners work, then you should be ok. So, you install the scanner software on the client side - and all it really does is press keys as if you were typing. So the trick then becomes to ensure that your cursor is in the right text box before you scan.